# getStoreCategories Filter by Array Id

Tags: magento-1.9, category

How can i filter **getStoreCategories()** collection by array of categories id?

this is my code

```
$category_list = array(764,765,766,768,779,767,772,769);
$obj = new Mage_Catalog_Block_Navigation();
$storeCategories = $obj->getStoreCategories();
```

I need to loop only categories witch id is in **$category_list** array

Comment: You can use array_diff function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Update code like this:

```
    $category_list = array(764,1,766,768,779,767,772,3);
    $catData = array();
    $obj = new Mage_Catalog_Block_Navigation();
    $storeCategories = $obj->getStoreCategories();
    foreach ($storeCategories as $key => $value) {
        if(in_array($value->getEntityId(),$category_list)){
            $catData[] = $value->getData();
        }
    }
    echo "<pre>";
    print_r($catData);
    exit;
```

Comment: Thanks now I'm using this solution but if it is possible I wanted to filter the collection a mount to make the loop faster

Comment: Please mark this solution as accepted, so others can also trust on same. 
I will try to give you a better solution tomorrow.